# Enviar 2 o más archivos tipo File por Postman

Tags: json, api, archivo, postman

soy nuevo trabajando con Postman, y necesito enviar a mi API 2 o mas fotos. La verdad es que pude realizar el envío de un archivo file en mi `"body" -> "form-data"` de Postman, pero  busqué y probé de muchas formas enviar 2 o más sin obtener un resultado positivo.
Les agradecería si me ayudan.
Lo ideal sería poder enviar un arreglo (o JSON) mas o menos asi:

```
{
    "photos_array": [
        {
            "file": "name_file",
            "action": "name_action",
            "picture_comment": "un comentario para la primera foto",
            "picture_timestamp": "12:00:00"
        },
        {
            "file": "name_file2",
            "action": "name_action",
            "picture_comment": "un comentario para la segunda foto",
            "picture_timestamp": "12:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```